# Streaming mp3 audio from a URL in circuitPython

Tags: python, mp3, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

I want to stream mp3 audio from a URL using the Raspberry Pi Pico W. This is my code:

```
import adafruit_requests
import wifi
import socketpool
import ssl
import board
import audiomp3
import audiobusio
import os

audio = audiobusio.I2SOut(board.GP10, board.GP11, board.GP9)

mp3_url = "http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/descent/background%20music.mp3"

chunk_size = 1024

wifi.radio.connect(os.getenv('WIFI_SSID'), os.getenv('WIFI_PASSWORD'))

pool = socketpool.SocketPool(wifi.radio)
requests = adafruit_requests.Session(pool, ssl.create_default_context())

try:
    doc = requests.get(mp3_url)
    
    with open('sound.mp3', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in doc.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            f.write(chunk)
            
    print("downloaded")
    mp3 = audiomp3.MP3Decoder(open("sound.mp3", "rb"))
    mp3.sample_rate=24000
    audio.play(mp3)
    
    while audio.playing:
        pass
    print("done playing")
except Exception as e:
    print("error in creating mp3 or playing audio:\n", str(e))
```

It currently downloads the mp3 in chunks and writes it to a file. The problem is, it takes too long, because I have to wait for the entire file to be downloaded first. How can I modify this code to start playing the audio after I send the request, and start streaming it as soon as enough data is available?

Comment: its not solution, its more like way to go: you need to confirm, that `audiobusio` supports streams.  What you basically need- define common buffer area, feed buffer with data from web and read from buffer to play audio

Answer (score 0):

@lixas is correct. You can pass a file to audiobusio, but not a stream.

https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/audiobusio/index.html